# How to reset the inputfile in form after submitting the form with a file in ADF

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf

I have a form where i have 3 input fields and one af:inputFile where i need to upload the file and final save.
I cannot use valueChangeEvent for inputFile because if i user ResetUtils then i will not get the form input values. 
On save everything works fine but when i again add a record then the last updated file still shows in inputFile(its not resetting).
After save if i set the input file binding to null then do partial trigger for the component using binding its loading the page taking huge time to save so i cant use it.

Here is my code

```
<af:panelFormLayout id="pfl1" rows="3">
<af:inputText value="#{bindings.Title.inputValue}" label="#{bindings.Title.hints.label}"
                                required="#{bindings.Title.hints.mandatory}"
                                columns="#{bindings.Title.hints.displayWidth}"
                                maximumLength="#{bindings.Title.hints.precision}"
                                shortDesc="#{bindings.Title.hints.tooltip}" id="it1" contentStyle="width:150px">
                    <f:validator binding="#{bindings.Title.validator}"/>
                  </af:inputText>
  <af:panelGroupLayout id="pgl350" layout="horizontal">
<af:inputFile label="Select" id="if51" value="#{ContractDocumentUploadDwn.file}"
showRequired="true" binding="#{ContractDocumentUploadDwn.inputFileBinding}"/>
<af:button text="Upload" id="b353" action="#{ContractDocumentUploadDwn.uploadPortfolioDoc}"/>
 </af:panelGroupLayout>
</af:panelFormLayout>
```

Java Code:

```
 public void savePortfolioDoc(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        // Add event code here...

        DCIteratorBinding iter = getDCIteratorBinding("portfolioDocument1Iterator");
        UploadedFile myfile = (UploadedFile) this.getInputFileBinding().getValue();
        String binding = "Commit1";
        String popUpId = "p2";
        genericSaveDocuments(actionEvent, iter, myfile, binding, popUpId, "Portfolio");//Saves the document
        iter.executeQuery();
        iter.refresh(1);
        setInputFileBinding(null);
        ResetUtils.reset(actionEvent.getComponent());

    }
```

Comment: Don't know, if this is the solution of your problem, but... look at your first line of your JSP at `<af:<panelFormLayout`, this is not a correct syntax. Perhaps this is why it's not working like expected.

Comment: I have edited my question, please check. There is no syntax error. while copying and pasting the code by mistake that character is entered.

Comment: Its all look like a mess, your description and code doesn' match. It looks like you have separate button to upload the file, why? If you submitting the form, you can use just submit button. In general you don't need to executeQuery or refresh for form. However you do need to call PPR action to form wrapper like `panelFormLayout` to make changes in bean visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't this the same question you asked at https://community.oracle.com/thread/3889350

Have you tried the solution given there?

```
public void savePortfolioDoc(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    // Add event code here...

    DCIteratorBinding iter = getDCIteratorBinding("portfolioDocument1Iterator");
    UploadedFile myfile = (UploadedFile) this.getInputFileBinding().getValue();
    String binding = "Commit1";
    String popUpId = "p2";
    genericSaveDocuments(actionEvent, iter, myfile, binding, popUpId, "Portfolio");//Saves the document
    this.getInputFileBinding().resetValue();
    this.setFile(null);
    // Reset inputFile component after upload
    ResetUtils.reset(this.getInputFileBinding());
    //iter.executeQuery();
    //iter.refresh(1);
}
```

Comment: OK, you uses the value property in the inputFile. You have to reset this too. I changed my code above.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VaHq.png)Just go to the popup where upload button is.
Then in properties **"Content Delivery"** set to **lazyUncache**
**"ChildChildren"** set to **Immediate**
**"Auto Cancel"** set to **Disable**
and last
**"ResetEditableValues"** set to **WhenCancel**
It will work properly
happy Coding :)